# How to connect to a docker container running on a remote host

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have two windows machines Machine A, Machine B running Windows 10 with Hyper-V. Both machine A & B are on the same network.

On Machine B I install docker using the Windows installer. I pull an image and then run it with:

`docker run -p 1337:1337 --name my-image`

On machine B I can then access the http end point that is exposed by opening a browser window to `http://127.0.0.1:1337`.

However I cannot seem to open that same http end point from machine A with:

`http://machineA.ip.address:1337`

There is no firewall between machine A and B.

Clearly I have a NAT problem between machine A and B when it comes to accessing the docker container on Machine B.

How do I access the HTTP end point exposed by the docker container running on Machine B from Machine A?

Comment: try with `docker run -p 0.0.0.0:1337:1337 --name my-image`

Comment: @fly2matrix Doh! Sp obvious. Happy to mark that as an answer if you like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expose docker guest port of container to bind it with host port.

```
$ docker run -p 0.0.0.0:1337:1337 --name my-image
```

Above command will bind it with all the network-interfaces.
If you want you can restrict access to specific network-interface by specific it's IP address.

Comment: Isn't "bind to all interfaces" the default?  Or is Docker for Windows special here?

Comment: when you specify 0.0.0.0 that means bind it with all the interfaces.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am guessing Windows is special here as it was only binding to localhost